# How do I add multiple Spring MVC controllers to my maven project

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to add multiple controllers to my Spring MVC project which only has one right now. My current project only has one SpringDispatcher in the web.xml and it maps the
      / 
to the '/' of the controllers 
     @RequestMapping(value = "/") 
start-up controller. Because everything is in the one web.xml and there are no other xml files that do any dispatcher mapping, should I not be able to just add a new 
     / 
with a different controller pattern to the web.xml? Below are the web.xml and the one working controller.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>SpringMvcJdbcTemplate</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>net.codejava.spring</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

HomeController.java

```
package net.codejava.spring.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.dao.ContactDAODS;
import net.codejava.spring.model.Contact;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * This controller routes accesses to the application to the appropriate
 * hanlder methods. 
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
private ContactDAO contactDAO;

@Autowired
private ContactDAODS contactDAODS;

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ModelAndView login() {

    Contact contact = new Contact();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
    model.addObject("contact", contact);

    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/loginContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginContact(@ModelAttribute Contact loginContact) {

    ModelAndView model;

    Contact contact = contactDAO.login(loginContact);

    if(contact != null)
    {
        model = new ModelAndView("menu");

        return model;

    }
    else
    {
        Map<String, String> message = new HashMap<String,   String>();
        message.put("message", "Login password error");
        //Message message = new Message();
        //message.MessageText = "Login Error";
        model = new ModelAndView("loginError");
        model.addObject("message", message);
        return model;

    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/menuContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView menu(ModelAndView model){
    model.setViewName("menu");

    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/listContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{
    List<Contact> listContact = contactDAO.list();
    model.addObject("listContact", listContact);
    model.setViewName("home");

    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/newContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView newContact(ModelAndView model) {
    Contact newContact = new Contact();
    model.addObject("contact", newContact);
    model.setViewName("ContactForm");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact) {
    contactDAO.saveOrUpdate(contact);       
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
    int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    contactDAO.delete(contactId);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
    int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    Contact contact = contactDAO.get(contactId);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ContactForm");
    model.addObject("contact", contact);

    return model;
}
@RequestMapping(value="/showContact")
public ModelAndView getContact(ModelAndView model) throws IOException{

    Contact contact = contactDAODS.get((Integer)25);
    model.addObject("contact", contact);
    model.setViewName("ContactSP");

    return model;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this mapping should only work for the application root. If you want any path under the application root then use
  /*

Now, in your case spring dispatcher will only be called if you open your browser to point to web application root without specifying any path which as i might guess is not what you want. So, use /* to forward all requests to the spring dispatcher and the use any request mapping in your controllers

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I have multiple controllers how do I get one controllers to call a request in another controller? Also, if there are multiple controllers how to I indicate the start-up controller and the start-up request?

Comment: If your application context name is "Holdorf" for example, so by using the URL pattern "/", spring dispatcher will receive requests only if you typed "http(s)://domain_name/Holdorf/" but if you typed "http(s)://domain_name/Holdorf/XXX" spring dispatcher won't take control. So you should use "/*" to forward all requests through spring dispatcher. Now, you can have as many controllers you want with different specific mappings. But you can't have two different controllers with same mappings

Comment: OK. I am starting to understand but not all the way. Do I still only have one <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> like that in the web.xml a just have a @requestmapping(value = "/") in the Holdorf controller that will be called automatically on startup. Then after that I call the rest of the controllers called like this "http(s)://domain_name/Holdorf2/getperson and if the two controllers are in the package folder then the domain_name would be the same?

Comment: Exactly..but application context "/Holderf/" cant be changed since its unique per whole web application. The domain name and the application context are fixed for all you request mappings. All your request mappings annotations in your controllers when starts by "/", you can replace this "/" in your mind as if you wrote "http(s)://domain_name/Holdorf/". So, in your controller if you wrote a mapping such as "/admin" then the web container understand it as"http(s)://domain_name/Holdorf/admin" and forward that request to the method annotated with this mapping. Hope this clarified things

Comment: So is what you are saying I need a separate package for each controller?

Comment: No..who mentioned packages here. I advice you to read and understand what application context means and where it appears in your url. Dont mix physical application structure with url pattern as they aren't related